# Pointwise convergence of step functions to logarithm on $(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I came up with a stepfunction on $(0,1]$:

$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln (\frac{i}{n}) \chi_{(\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]} $, where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function.

I need to show that this function converges pointwise to $\ln(x)$. From the definition I need to proof that $\forall x \in (0,1], \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n\geq N : |s_n - \ln(x) | < \epsilon$.

Now I take a $x \in (0,1]$ and pick $\epsilon >0$. Now I need to choose a $N$, but I don't know a good construction (does anybody have a hint?). Once I have this $N$, I see that $\forall n\geq N: x \in (\frac{i-1}{n} , \frac{i}{n}]$ for some $i$. Then I only need to prove that: $|\ln(\frac{i}{n}) - \ln(x)| < \epsilon$, but how to achieve this is a mystery for me.

Comment: Can you prove the uniform convergence on an interval $[t,1]$ with $0\lt t\lt1$?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for any continuous function $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ the sequence
$$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) \chi_{(\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]}$$
converges to $f$ pointwise on $(0,1]$.

Given $x\in  (0,1]$, consider the restriction of $f$ smaller *closed* interval $[x,1]$ (following Did's hint). Since $f$ is continuous on this interval, it's uniformly continuous. So, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta$... as in the definition of uniform continuity, and then any $n>1/\delta$ works.